# bonita bpm 7-web form does not open in bonita portal

Tags: bonita

I am beginner to bonita when run  bonita it say "this is a temporary form generated automatically for testing. Before you put your process into production, create and map the necessary forms".

Answer (score 1):

Bonita is just telling you that you have a **Human Task**, a task that is to be completed by a user, and you haven't created/assigned a form.

All you have to do is create a form for all the human-type tasks; if you have a contract defined, it will autogenerate a form according to the contract.

[image: click the pencil to edit the form]

Answer (score -2):

Your post is a bit vague but here are some resources.

You could start by watching these ["getting started" videos](http://community.bonitasoft.com/blog/examples-and-video-tutorials-bonita-bpm-7).
Then, you can also refer to the [official documentation](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/).

Hope this helps,

Comment: No, this does not help. Please familiarize yourself with what constitutes an acceptable post on Stack Overflow. Both this question and your answer do not qualify. If you see a vague and unspecific question like this, flag it for closure instead of attempting to write an answer. And "here's a link to the docs" should at most be a comment, not an answer. By the way, the fact that your documentation is behind a login wall is IMO extremely stupid and caused me to instantly disregard your product for an upcoming project - we chose jbpm instead. That the login is easily circumvented makes it worse.